# NullReferenceException in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

One of my if statements is throwing a null reference exception.  The thing is, the statement contains a lot of objects and variables. Is there any way to check which object instance is causing the problem? I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Professional.

```
for(i=0;i<(row*row);i++)
{
    int flag=0;
    if ((r[rno].load < load_limit)  &&((r[rno].points.Count()) < (row - 1))&&(r[rno].check(list[i].pos.row)) && ((r[rno].load + c[list[i].pos.row].load) <= 10) && ((r[rno].load + c[list[i].pos.col].load <= 10)))
    {
        r[rno].points.Add(list[i].pos.row);
        r[rno].load+=c[list[i].pos.row].load;
        flag=1;
        if((r[rno].load==load_limit)||((r[rno].points.Count())==(row-1)))
        {
            r[rno].points.Add(0);
            rno++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, debugging.. See [Debugging in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx)

Comment: 'route[] r = new route[row - 1];
                  int load_limit = 10;
                  int rno;
                rno=0;
                for(i=0;i<(row*row);i++)
                {
                    int flag=0;
                    if ((r[rno].load < load_limit)  &&((r[rno].points.Count()) < (row - 1))&&(r[rno].check(list[i].pos.row)) && ((r[rno].load + c[list[i].pos.row].load) <= 10) && ((r[rno].load + c[list[i].pos.col].load <= 10)))
                    '
Its complicated

Comment: Change the `if` to this, so you won't have any dots in your `if` (apart from `rowObject.check()`, but that can't throw there): `var rowObject = r[rno];
var rowLoad = rowObject.load;
var pointCount = rowObject.points.Count();
var rowToCheck = list[i].pos.row;
var loadCompensation = c[list[i].pos.row].load;` Then change the `if` to: `if ((rowLoad < load_limit)
 && ((pointCount) < (row - 1))
 && (rowObject.check(rowToCheck))
 && ((rowLoad + loadCompensation) <= 10) 
 && ((rowLoad + loadCompensation <= 10)))`. Now you'll get the `NullReferenceException` in a somewhat more useful place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be your code, and it is easy to spot where is the error....

```
route[] r = new route[row - 1]; 
int load_limit = 10;  int rno; 
rno=0; 

for(i=0;i<(row*row);i++) 
{ 
    int flag=0; 
    if ((r[rno].load < load_limit) && 
       ((r[rno].points.Count()) < (row - 1)) &&
        (r[rno].check(list[i].pos.row)) && 
        ((r[rno].load + c[list[i].pos.row].load) <= 10) && 
        ((r[rno].load + c[list[i].pos.col].load <= 10)))
```

In the first line you create an array of `row-1` route elements. But this array is just a container for a fixed number of `route` objects. The slots of the array are all empty. You cannot use a slot of this array and pretending to use that empty slot as if it contains a valid `route` instance.

When you try to use the `load` property in this line `r[rno].load` you are accessing the zero index of the array `r` but at this index you have no `route` instance on which you could use the `load` property. Hence the null reference exception.

To fix that, before accessing that index, you need to initialize the array slot with a valid route instance....

```
r[rno] = new route();
```

Answer (score 2):

Run it in a debugger and check each object. Or, better, put null checks inside your code.

Comment: that could be comment

Comment: Uhm, no. OP's question is _"Is there any way to check which object instance is causing the problem?"_. There are at least two, mentioned by this answer: inspecting them either in the debugger or checking them by code at runtime.

Comment: I used the debugging and its showing me the line by the exception is thrown but not the object

Comment: See [Viewing Data in the Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esta7c62.aspx). I suspect for example `r[rno]` and `c[list[i].pos.row]` can be `null`.

Comment: Split onto more lines.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use breakpoints and when you reach the statement throwing the exception, then use the [visual studio immediate window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx) to find out the statement causing the exception. In the immediate window you could execute each partial statement and check if it returns null.

In general, you should not use multiple statements in one coding line. This leads to code hard to maintain and debug (as in your case). Perhaps refactoring the specific code snippet would be a good choice.

Hope I helped!